Angular Fire Functions - app.functions is not a function
I am using Angular v16 with Angular Fire v16 and Firebase v9. I did all the setup like in the instructions. I did the firebase login, firebase init and made the functions to typescript.
Then I imported AngularFireFunctionsModule into my app.module.ts:
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,   //imported here
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, 
  ],

For testing I just created this simple index.ts:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.callMe = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return data.name
});

I deployed it using firebase deploy and it worked. Also checked on the console website and I can see it there.
I am using a service called bubbleService which calls it:
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
...
...
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BubbleService {

  constructor(
    ...
    public functions: AngularFireFunctions
  ) { } 

  callFunction(name: string): Promise<string> {
    const callable = this.functions.httpsCallable('callMe');
    return callable({ name }).toPromise().then((result) => {
      return result.data as string;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error calling function:', error);
      throw error;
    });
  }

....

And this service is being called by my component:
this.bubbleService.callFunction('John Doe').then((data) => {
      alert(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Failed to fetch greeting:', error);
});

However now when I run this, i get this error in my web console:

Error calling function: TypeError: app.functions is not a function

I have tried multiple versions of Angular Fire but it didn't work. I honestly have no idea what to do or what this means.

The import is wrong, we need to change it like below!
BEFORE:
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

AFTER:
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

Fire function github docs

Module '"@angular/fire/functions"' has no exported member 'AngularFireFunctions'.ts(2305) - Thats the error I get, as said I use Angular/Fire 16 which uses the compat for some reason in the newer versions.
